# Language in URL, Routing and Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I've learned so far how to set up a correct routing if I would like to have the language within the URL, e.g. `.../en/MyController/MyMethod`. With the following routing this works great so far:

```
        routes.MapRoute("Default with language", "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",     
        new
        {
            controller = "Report",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
        }, new { lang = "de|en" });
        // Standard-Routing
        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
        {
            controller = "Report",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
            lang = "de",
        });
```

Now I Inserted a new area `Cms`, and I call `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` in Application_Start().

As soon as I call a controller within this area, I miss the language-key:

```
        MvcHandler handler = Context.Handler as MvcHandler;
        if (handler == null)
            return;

        string lang = handler.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] as string;
```

How could I make the above routing work with areas?

Thx for any tipps, sl3dg3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following routing works now in my case (the area is called `Cms`):

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyProject.Areas.Cms
{
    public class CmsAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Cms";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {

        context.MapRoute("Cms_default_with_language", "Cms/{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
            lang = "de",
        }, new { lang = "de|en" });
        context.MapRoute(
            "Cms_default",
            "Cms/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, lang = "de" }
        );

        }
    }
}
```

The only thing I'm not quite happy about: now I have more or less duplicate code in Global.asax and in this class. Is there a way to avoid these duplicate mappings?

Comment: I don't think it's meant to answer your own questions with updates like this. 
Anyway. I think your Area route registration needs the the `AreaName` from the `AreaRegistration` and that's why it needs to be in the override there.

Comment: @Mike, why not answer my own question? Basically it forms a complete solution to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the generated class that derives from `AreaRegistration`, named `[AreaName]AreaRegistration`.

It contains a route registration as well, this is the default:

```
context.MapRoute(
   "AreaName_default",
   "AreaName/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```